# asp.net web site publish failure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc, filereference

I am using vs2010, asp.net website having mysql database.
all i need to ask is:

when i build solution,rebuild solution,build website,rebuild website. it succeeds.
but when i publish it on another folder it gives me this error on almost every page of my application.

```
Error   1   Circular file references are not allowed.
```

how am i suppose to deploy my website even on iis or my local machine??
I have tried batch="false" in the compilation part (web.config). 
but no use.

please help. thanx in advance.

Comment: there is no double or triple or cross references in my application as i have it myself so i know!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729153/circular-file-references-not-allowed) thread. It looks like the same issue with a lot of helpful advice going on.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you got it sorted. :)