# Circular references on every page when opening project on another computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, circular-reference

In order to work on my website on a second computer, I put the project on an usb key and opened it.
The initial project is building correctly, but whenever I try to open it on the second machine, I have a circular reference issue on every single page and can't figure out why.

For each aspx page, I've got:

```
Circular file references are not allowed. MyPage.aspx. Line 1.
```

For instance, here's the first line of "Profile.aspx":

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Game/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="Profile" %>
```

Site.master is actually in the same folder "Game" as all the other pages, and moving this master page in another folder seems to do the trick. However, this doesn't make sens since this is working correctly elsewhere...

Another odd thing: If I keep the project on the usb key (not working if I move the folder) and comment those lines, there is no circular references anymore:

```
public static class Database
{
    private static string conxString = "";

    static Database()
    {
        /*System.IO.StreamReader dataBaseFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("~/Files/DataBase.txt");
        conxString = dataBaseFile.ReadToEnd();
        dataBaseFile.Close();*/
    }
}
```

Where database.txt contains the local database connection string.

If anyone has any idea please feel free, I really don't know how to address this matter.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729153/circular-file-references-not-allowed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I did, however I didn't create any new master page nor changed folders excepted the project's one itself. Can't see how changing project's folder could create circular references on every page, and can't find any clue of what is really the matter; the master page, or may be the database.txt file