# Circular reference ASPNET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins, circular-reference, aspnet-compiler

I just want to say that I'm not that familiar with aspnet first. I have been given this 6 yo application that Im trying to automate using Jenkins. (I didnt choose this life if it was for me I'd have re-written the whole thing using something not from the stone ages...)

Anyways it compiles locally but when i try to build it using jenkins - which is i guess similar to building using command line arguments - i get the error ASPPARSE: Circular
file references are not allowed. I understand the error but i cant find it mainly because im not familiar with the aspnet syntaxes i believe. I'm also aware that i can add `batch=false` to my `<compilation>` in webconfig but that creates memory related errors in the Jenkins machine.

> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The application domain in which the
>   thread was running has been unloaded.

I looked up online and all the posts are either too generic that i dont know how to apply to my solution or not applicable at all.

I believe problem is caused in the files due to these tags 

Sorry.aspx (Sorry.aspx.cs is in the same directory):

```
<%@Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Sorry.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sorry" %>
```

and in the same directory Site.master:

```
<%@Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>
```

I'm really struggling to understand how there is a circular reference maybe there is something else im missing?
Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT- I receive the following error:

```
16:25:21   /Sorry.aspx(1): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [F:\JENKINS-SLAVE\workspace\Branch_4.04.000\website.publishproj]
16:25:21   /ManualTransactionInput.aspx(1): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [F:\JENKINS-SLAVE\workspace\Branch_4.04.000\website.publishproj]
16:25:21   /Default.aspx(1): error ASPPARSE: Circular file references are not allowed. [F:\JENKINS-SLAVE\workspace\Branch_4.04.000\website.publishproj]
```

Comment: kindly provide the circular ref error details to try to tell you exactly which references are not correct and how to manage it

Comment: Hi @HanyHabib I thank you for your comment! I editted my question with the exact error I got

Comment: [Publish Web-site causes 'Circular file references are not allowed.'](https://forums.asp.net/t/2021417.aspx?Publish+Web+site+causes+Circular+file+references+are+not+allowed+)

Comment: @let_the_coding_begin what are the _memory related errors_, when you add `batch=false` configuration?

Comment: hey @laika thanks for commenting! this is the error that i get when i add `batch=false` -> ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The application domain in which the thread was running has been unloaded.

Comment: Any ideas anyone? @laika

Comment: I have experienced this before with user controls (.ascx file) and having to use directories to get rid of the error (i.e., one control can't reference another in the same directory, I believe). But that was years ago, and it happened when compiling locally.  Is there anything in the code behind that may be causing this?

Comment: @ps2goat I'm not sure as I'm not that familiar with the code yet but no afaik.. So you are saying moving those files into a separate directory should fix the problem?

Comment: maybe.  it looks like it worked for someone else on SO.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991387/2084315

Comment: @ps2goat im so confused though this is not an issue in my local system it just creates this problem in Jenkins...